# Perl hash key determined by array

Tags: perl, arrays, hash

I have an array and I am making a hash instance from it. 
For instance, if array is:

```
@folders=(temp,usr,bin);
```

then i want to fill in hash:

```
$the_path{$folders[0]}{$folders[1]}{$folders[2]}="somevalue";
```

But if the array is only:

```
@folders=(bin);
```

then i want the path to be:

```
$the_path{$folders[0]}="somevalue";
```

The problem is I dont know beforehand how long the array is gonna be, and I would really like to avoid making *x* if statements for that solution scales terribly.

How do I do this?

Comment: You've got `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of your file, right? That will catch many errors for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, that's not how you define an array in Perl. You probably want to say

```
my @folders = ( 'temp', 'usr', 'bin' );
```

There's an old trick for making nested hash keys from a list:

```
my %the_path;
my $tmp = \%the_path;
foreach my $item( @folders ) { 
    $tmp->{$item} = { };
    $tmp = $tmp->{$item};
}
```

This will result in a structure like the following:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'temp' => {
                      'usr' => {
                                 'bin' => {}
                               }
                    }
        };
```

If you want to replace the empty hashref at the bottom-most level with a string, you can keep track of a count variable inside the loop.

Comment: As always, we already have CPAN modules for that. [Data::Diver](http://p3rl.org/Data::Diver) is my favourite.